# Landsat WMS into QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, landsat

I have following questions:

> Access Landsat image(s) web services in QGIS
>   And can I do analysis based on these WMS?

Is it possible?

if so, when I tried to access from Layers>Add Rasters> the formats shows all but not WMS image service?

Is there any other method to do so?

do I need to install any extension to for WMS images?

or through Python programs?

Comment: The service you link to in your comment on the answer (https://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/) is not an OGC WMS/WMTS so most of your question is invalid.

Comment: You can download any tif from the server by appending a key value to the base URL.  but I don't think you can just add a raster from a URL, so you will need to download it first

Comment: Thanks, but I heard it's possible to read image URL into the software

Comment: But not as a WMS.  If you read that it was possible, then can you reference your sources, in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can add WMS layer through Layer>Add Layer>Add WMS/WMTS Layer.

Comment: Thanks for reply ..however Im unable to add/use these aws tiles into qgis...following is the url..can you pls suggest a way to read in qgis ?                     https://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/c1/L8/139/045/LC08_L1TP_139045_20170304_201
70316_01_T1/index.htm

Comment: I get following error, may be that's the cause of you problem.
<Error>
<script/>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>c1/L8/139/045/LC08_L1TP_139045_20170304_201</Key>
<RequestId>87D0453E00BB70EC</RequestId>
<HostId>
DM8adXlY0BQWtBJmJFHZ1ih3YElubo1lhQjBFQFKqbvbu2mYk+SSeEMMqxd9XeMWAqXbUbkE8vc=
</HostId>
</Error>